# PHP: http_build_query return strange symbol

Tags: php

I run the same code in two different servers and I got different results

```
$dataS = array(
  'v' => '1',
  'tid' => 'test',
 );

$dataS = http_build_query($dataS);
```

One server:

```
v=1&tid=test
```

Other server:

```
v=1&amp;tid=test
```

Why result is not the same?
How get the same result in both servers, because now only first result is good.

Comment: Could you provide some more info about the differences between your servers, such as php version, OS, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other answers already suggested, your issue comes from the `$arg_separator` argument in `http_build_query()`.

More precisely, since you didn't populate it, the function uses its default value *which depends on the server configuration*, as stated by http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php:

> **arg_separator**
>   [arg_separator.output](http://%20arg_separator%20%20%20%20%20%20arg_separator.output%20is%20used%20to%20separate%20arguments%20but%20may%20be%20overridden%20by%20specifying%20this%20parameter.) is used to separate arguments but may be overridden by specifying this parameter.

And following the `arg_separator.output` link you get:

> **arg_separator.output string**
>       The separator used in PHP generated URLs to separate arguments.

So it appears that your different servers have different configurations, hence the different results.
To get rid of that you may either:

- change the server configuration where it does not match your preferred separator
- or always include the `$arg_separator` in your `http_build_query()`

BTW please note:

> only first result is good

is not true: using `&amp;` is well suited to most situations, and always understood and correctly processed.